# Ошибка 403 при загрузке карты через JavaScript API Яндекса

Tags: javascript, api, яндекс-карты

Создал html-файл (index.html) и подключил Яндекс карту в соответствии с документацией на сайте. Html-файл разместил в директории C:\inetpub\wwwroot\ на Windows Server 2019 (web-сервер IIS).
При простом открытии файла index.html или по URL-адресу http://localhost/index.html карта загружается и работает без проблем, но при попытке открыть через ip адрес сервера страница загружается - видны все элементы, но div для карты остается пустым. В инструментах разработчика в Network вижу, что при открытии страницы при попытке загрузить карту получаем ошибку 403 (в запросе используется невалидный API-ключ)
Рекомендации Яндекса по этой теме выполнил (https://yandex.ru/dev/developer-help/doc/troubleshooting/key.html).
Ключ бесплатный с ограничениями (JavaScript API и HTTP Геокодер), не заблокированный, написан правильно и без пробелов, лимит не исчерпан, IIS настроен по умолчанию. Погуглил, но решения так и не нашел.
Помогите разобраться в чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вопросы о возможной блокировке доменов, IP и работе ключей следует задавать в поддержку API Яндекс.Карт - **maps-api@support.yandex.ru**

Обратите внимание, по [условиям](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsapi/doc/2.1/terms/index-docpage/) бесплатного тарифа карта должна быть размещена на публичном сервере, доступном для любого пользователя сети.